# How to generate iteratively all subsets for an array in Prolog, and store them into another array?

Tags: arrays, prolog, iteration, subset

I know that it is very easy recursively with this code

```
subsets([], []).
subsets([E|Tail], [E|NTail]):-
   subsets(Tail, NTail).
subsets([_|Tail], NTail):-
   subsets(Tail, NTail).
```

But I want to store them into an array by generating them iteratively.For example: L=[1,2,3] -> Result = [[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]].

Comment: `findall(Subset, subsets(Set, Subset), Subsets)`? (A better name for `subsets/2` would be `subset/2` since it succeeds if the second argument is **a** subset of the first argument.)

Comment: It works.Thank you!

Comment: These are lists, not arrays, and it is not possible in Prolog to "store" values "into" an array in any direct sense. I bring it up because using imperative vocabulary suggests you have an imperative mindset, which will become a bigger problem for you as you try to do more complicated things.

Comment: Thank you for the adivce! I study prolog at university, so I do pretty basic things,nothing complicated.But of course this is not an excuse to adopt bad practices!